# how should I solve my NullPointerException?

Tags: java, lucene, nullpointerexception, indexing, neo4j

I really don not know what else to do,I have searched every where,tried anything but could not solve my problem.I created a neo4j graph database and created an index on name property of nodes through localhost:7474(visually),now I want to get the node numbers by searching their name property index,but I get nullpointerexception error,I know this is because of existing a null value,and I know where is this from,but I can not solve it.

this is the code:

```
package graph_traversing;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.Index;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.IndexHits;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.IndexManager;

public class search_string extends javax.swing.JFrame
{


    public search_string() {initComponents(); }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
{
    INCLUDES
} 

  private static final String DB_PATH = "C:\\Users\\fereshteh\\Downloads\\Compressed\\neo4j-community-1.9.4\\DB";
  GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
 IndexManager nodeindex = db.index();
 Index<Node> names = nodeindex.forNodes( "name" );

    String [] str;
    Node [] nodes;Relationship rel;
    IndexHits<Node> hits;

    String find;
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        search_txb = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        search_btn = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText(" Enter The Word Please");

        search_btn.setText("Search");
        search_btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                search_btnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(search_btn)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 147, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(search_txb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addComponent(search_txb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 71, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(search_btn)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void search_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        str=search_txb.getText().split(" ");

       for(int i=0;i<str.length;++i)
        {
            find=str[i];
            hits = names.get("name", find);
            System.out.println(hits);
            nodes [i] = hits.getSingle();
          // nodes [i]= nodeIndex.get( "name", find ).getSingle();
           System.out.println(nodes[i]);
        }
       String s ="hi";
       for(int i=0;i<nodes.length;++i)
       {
         rel= (Relationship) nodes[i].getRelationships();
         for(int j=i+1;j<nodes.length;++j)
         {
           s=rel.toString();

         }
       }
     System.out.println(s);

    }                                          


    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {new search_string().setVisible(true);} });




    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton search_btn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField search_txb;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

the error firstly belongs to this line:  `nodes [i] = hits.getSingle();`

I have changed it and  `hits = names.get("name", find);` to so many other codes,but always get the error.

and this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at graph_traversing.search_string.search_btnActionPerformed(search_string.java:90)
    at graph_traversing.search_string.access$000(search_string.java:14)
    at graph_traversing.search_string$1.actionPerformed(search_string.java:50)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have put  `System.out.println(hits);` to understand whether hits is null or not,but I see in output hits have  `org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex$1@481f3834` value(is this the right output?I expected to get the nodes).

this is java api,and this will be really really kind of you if you help me,please,I have got dizziness.

Comment: Many objects do not have a great toString() method and will not implicitly give you the println(...) output you desire. Call System.out.println(hits.currentScore()) on hits variables specifically if there's a variable you want printed, or else you'll have to write a custom printGraph(...) method which iterates through hits.next() and prints each.

Comment: Please indent your code consistently for readability. I fixed your (almost) [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637017/how-to-solve-exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexcepti) 13 hours ago. If you feel you have to post the same question again already, you should consider bringing the corrected indentation with: the more readable your question, the more likely you are to get accurate help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not initializing `nodes` to anything. You're getting a null pointer from trying to access index `i` of `null` at `nodes[i]`.

I *think* what you want to do is initialize `nodes` in your `search_btnActionPerformed` method, something like...

```
private void search_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    str=search_txb.getText().split(" ");
    // initialize nodes to a new array with the same size as str
    nodes = new Node[str.length]; 
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;++i)
    ......

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hits = names.get("name", find);
```

Can return null. You need to check for that, or otherwise guarantee it will not be null. Maybe the string you're passing in isn't correct (are you sure "name" is a node?). That said, you should check for null if it could be null; only print if the value is null. Otherwise you can throw an exception or print an error or try again:

```
if(hits != null){
            System.out.println(hits);
            nodes [i] = hits.getSingle();
            if(nodes[i] != null){
                     System.out.println(nodes[i]);
            }
    }
else{
    System.out.println("'name' not found);
}
```

Comment: excuse me,name,is not a node,it is the property which got indexed.